# Prove $x^6 + y^6 + z^6 + 3x^2y^2z^2 \geq 2(x^3y^3 + y^3z^3 + z^3x^3)$

Tags: inequality

For $x,y,z>0$, prove
$$
x^6 + y^6 + z^6 + 3x^2y^2z^2 \geq 2(x^3y^3 + y^3z^3 + z^3x^3)
$$

Answer (score 1):

By Schur and Muirhead 
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^6+x^2y^2z^2)\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^4y^2+x^4z^2)\geq2\sum\limits_{cyc}x^3y^3$$
Done!

Comment: Tnx, Schur was the crucial step. This can't be done only with Muirhead.

Comment: @Mak Of course! $\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^4y^2+x^4z^2-2x^3y^3)=\sum\limits_{cyc}x^2y^2(x-y)^2\geq0$